# Rdio style pop up box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to create a pop up box very similar to how Rdio does it on their site. On Rdio when you click on a user's thumbnail a popup box appears with the users profile details. I'm wondering how I could accomplish something like this. I'm developing my site in Ruby on Rails. The first thing that comes to mind is jQuery Dialogs. Would I also need Ajax? Any Ideas?

Here is a link to Rdio. On the right sidebar hover over user thumbnail and click on down arrow. Popbox will appear. http://www.rdio.com/#/artist/Kings_Of_Leon/album/Only_By_The_Night_1/

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely plenty of jQuery plugins to do this. I myself stay away from them because I feel to have full control over what I'm doing its best to create it myself. If you want the simplest, quickest solution I would say qTip is a very easy solution.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Otherwise the basic concept to MIMIC what you see on the rdio site would be to wrap each user thumbnail in a relative div and give it a second child to hold the extra data that is hidden and absolute. You can give things ID's that have the id of the user appended to them. Then, when the viewer clicks on a thumbnail you can use ajax to retrieve the necessary HTML from a php page.

```
<div class="wrap relative">
  <div class="thumbnail" id="user_1"></div>
  <div class="hidden absolute" id="userinfo_1">user info will go here</div>
</div>
```

Now some simple JS to get you on your way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
    // this will get the ID of the element and extract the user ID from it
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_').pop();

    // use ajax and send the user id to a page to retrieve HTML
    // and place this into the hidden info div and show it
    $.get(
      "getinfo.php",
      {"user_id" : id}
      function(data){
        $('#userinfo_'+id).html(data).show();
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Obviously you will have to account for clicking out of the div to re-hide the user info in some fashion. You could possibly make a **X** div inside the HTML from the php page that automatically hides it, but that would require some extra JS that I wont get into right now.

You will also want to use **top** and **left** css attributes to position your info div where you would like it.

This is obviously a very simple start, but I hope it fuels your idea.